# Vocabulary Term Translation Edit/Delete Page Get Access Denied/ Doesn't Function Correctly

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I currently have a taxonomy term with multiple translations. When I visit the translate tab for the term it does list all of the languages properly.

[image]

However no matter what translation I'm attempting to edit, it takes me to the edit page for English. I found that it seems to automatically send you to the edit page of the translation that matches the user's set Site language.

If I change the site language of the admin user to Spanish no matter what edit link I click it only takes me to the Spanish translation. The admin user has access to all allowed languages so I'm not sure why it would restrict all access to the specified site default language.

[image]

Side note if I attempt to delete a specific translation it deletes all translations.
If I manually enter this path

```
/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term_id}/translations/edit/{language}
```

I get an access denied page. 
I shouldn't ever get an access denied page because I'm an admin with all 
permissions enabled.
I do believe this path should exist because looking at the routes associated with the taxonomy term entity does contain that path. Here is some of the content of the entity info produced by devel.

```
[links:protected] => Array
    (
        [canonical] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}
        [delete-form] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/delete
        [edit-form] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/edit
        [create] => /taxonomy/term
        [devel-load] => /devel/taxonomy_term/{taxonomy_term}
        [devel-render] => /devel/taxonomy_term/{taxonomy_term}/render
        [devel-definition] => /devel/taxonomy_term/{taxonomy_term}/definition
        [token-devel] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/devel/token
        [drupal:content-translation-overview] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/translations
        [drupal:content-translation-add] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/translations/add/{source}/{target}
        [drupal:content-translation-edit] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/translations/edit/{language}
        [drupal:content-translation-delete] => /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/translations/delete/{language}
    )
```

Why can't I access the edit forms for the translations that don't match the users set site language? How can I fix this?

Comment: This is probably about how you've configured language detection. Did you change the default settings?

Comment: I Have these enabled: Selected language, User.

Comment: I think you need to add either URL (preferrable) or Session with a higher priority.

Comment: I attempted that. No luck. To be clear (in the first image with the list of languages and the edit button) the edit buttons all have the same url. So I am not sure how it would know which translation to fetch with no extra information. Also the Entity Info suggests it should be '/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/translations/edit/{language}'. Which it is not.

Comment: Sure this works, if you have URL detection the edit button will point to the language specific prefix. Concerning the workflow of content translation, not all things work like they should, there are still some open issues. So it is not necessarily your fault. You have to play around with language detection for non standard language settings.

Comment: You were right just check "Content language" under "Content language detection".

Answer (score 0):

Just check "Content language" under "Content language detection".